# How do I rename properties or public fields after moving them to another class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I have fields in one class and I want to move them to another class. Creating the new fields is not that much work. Changing all their references from the class they were in until now, however - is.

‘Rename’ doesn’t accept ‘myClass.Field’ as valid. Is changing using Find-and-Replace the only option (though then I’ll have to check every occurrence because of identically-named variables)? Or is there a simple way like ‘Rename’?

Comment: ReSharper can do this. I don't believe Visual Studio can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no (built-in) refactoring that will move a variable to another type.  Some third party refactoring tools (such as Resharper) do include this as additional features.

However, I would recommend letting the compiler help you instead of relying on Find and Replace.  If you remove the original variables, every access of the variable will become an instant compiler error.  This will give you all of the usages without false positives.

Comment: Note that this method works as long as all access to the property are made "normally". If you access it somewhere through reflexion or through a dynamic, the compiler will not be able to help you (but neither will a tool like resharper). You will have to use old find and replace.

Comment: @Falanwe Yes - unfortunately, that also means that any Xaml binding will break, as well - those need to be handled manually (since they're done "by name" instead of a direct prop. access)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
 1. Ensure everything compiles well first :)
 2. Move your variable into the new class `MyClass`
 3. Add a field `MyClass myClass` to the original class and instantiate it in the constructor
 4. Using a text editor (as VS does not allow this) search for all instances of `Field` and replace them by `myClass.Field`
 5. Back to VS, compile your code again
This should work fine and should save you some valuable time.

Regards,